# Facebook keeps telling me I'm on a new device

Tags: facebook

For some reason Facebook on my Ubuntu desktop keeps telling me I'm logging in from a new device, and I have to go through the rigmarole of proving my identity every time I go to Facebook. FB works fine on my Android 'phone, and on my Ubuntu laptop. I've tried clearing all the cache and cookies in Firefox, and even tried a different browser (Opera).

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Firefox 95.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Are you using an installed system? (that behavior is expected on *live* systems)   I would also check what extensions you have installed as some intentionally act that way so each session is a new identity (*for privacy reasons*)

Comment: Do you use a VPN?

Comment: *"I've tried clearing all the cache and cookies"* - this will produce the opposite effect from what you want. Make sure that your browser **does not** automatically clear or restrict Facebook's access to personal stored information that is required for your browser to stay logged in.  Many settings that increase privacy have a trade-off: if you prevent your browser from remembering personal info or if you prevent websites from accessing personal data from your browser, it can inhibit the methods that websites use to recognize that you're using the same device.

Comment: Yes, keeping Facebook cookies seems to solve the problem, but then it bypasses all my security when I go to FB,

Comment: If you have a FB account, FB tracks you EVERYWHERE. Cookies are only the tip of the iceberg.